# how to pass the custom format provider with ecsFormat in winston.format.combine

Tags: node.js, winston

I am using winston.format.combine

and passing the ecsFormat and customeFormat provider

```
this.logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: this.level,
  format: winston.format.combine(ecsFormat(), this.formatProvider.createFormat(this.category)),
  transports: [new Console()],
});
```

}

but this giving me the TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON.

Let me know if there is a way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found the answer for this,

```
logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: this.level,
  format: (ecsFormat(), this.formatProvider.createFormat(this.category)),
  transports: [new Console()],
});
```